# Is it possible to test a class method with MiniTest (e.g. Foo.bar)?

Tags: ruby, minitest

How can I test that `Foo.bar` is being called in the following example without testing the behavior of the `bar` method (which is already tested elsewhere)?

```
# Code
class Alpha
  def process
    Foo.bar
  end
end
```

The following spec is what I have so far.  Unfortunately, this approach throws a "class already defined" warning since Foo has already been defined elsewhere in my project.

```
 # Spec
 let(:alpha) { Alpha.new }
 let(:klass) { MiniTest::Mock.new }

 subject { alpha.process }

 it "calls Foo.bar" do
   klass.expect(:bar, '')     # Define method call expectation
   Foo = klass                # Redefine Foo as a mock object
   subject                    # Run method being tested
   klass.verify               # Confirm method was called
 end
```

*I don't want my test to depend on the `Foo` class since that is an external dependency and I don't want to test the response value of `Foo.bar`, since that may change arbitrarily.*

Answer (score 6):

In order to mock out a class like this you have to insert an injection point like so:

```
class Alpha
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @foo_class = opts[:foo_class] || Foo
  end

  def process
    @foo_class.bar
  end
end
```

This works because a class name is simply a constant in Ruby, which can be assigned like any other value.  So rather than hard-coding the call to the `Foo` class in `Alpha`, you are now calling the method on whatever your new `@foo_class` instance variable points to.  Most of the time this will still be class `Foo` unless you pass in something else.  I normally hide mock parameters like this as optional params as I did here.  I also don't include references to them in end-user targeted documentation, because they're technically not a part of what I consider to be the public API.

Then in your test, you can initialize your `Alpha` object like so:

```
fooClassMock = MiniTest::Mock.new
fooClassMock.expect(:bar, '')
alpha = Alpha.new(:foo_class => fooClassMock)
```

And you should get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Correct, indeed. What if my "process" method (as per your example above) should do @foo_class.new.bar? Which should be my expects? fooClassMock.expect(:bar, '') it's easy, but the other one should be fooClassMock.expect(:new, Foo) or something else? I'm not able to mock something like this. Any hint?

Comment: @user1955626 Actually, instead of expecting `:new`, I believe you should expect `:initialize`. The return value of `initialize` should be another `Mock` that expects `:bar` and returns the appropriate value. But whether it is expecting `:new` or `:initialize`, the key is to return another `Mock` that expects `:bar`.

Comment: Okay on epecting `:initialize`. What about the returned result? Should it be `fooClassMock.expect(:initialize, the_other_mock.class)` or `fooClasssMock.expect(:initialize, the_other_mock.new)` or something like that? Obviously having written the new mock like `the_other_moc = MiniTest::Mock.new` and the specific expectation on `:bar` method.

Comment: This is getting long for comments, feel free to open a question on it and I'll answer it there where I don't have only 500 characters and I can give you a syntax-highlighted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but I was looking for a solution for this that didn't require modifying business code to make tests easier, and I think I came up with a solution.

Even if you're using Rails, you need to add `gem "minitest"` to your `Gemfile`, then add `require "minitest/mock"` to your `test_helper.rb`.

```
it "calls Foo.bar" do
  bar_is_called = false
  bar_lambda = ->{
    bar_is_called = true
  }

  Foo.stub(:bar, bar_lambda) do
    Alpha.new.process
  end
  bar_is_called.must_equal true
end
```

`.stub` can be passed a return value, or when passed something that responds to `.call`, it calls `.call` on it ([Docs for the stub method](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Object.html)). In this example. `bar_lambda` is called, changing the value of `bar_is_called`. This verifies that `Foo.bar` was called.

It also works similarly in test syntax:

```
test 'Foo.bar is called' do
  bar_is_called = false
  bar_lambda = ->{
    bar_is_called = true
  }

  Foo.stub(:bar, bar_lambda) do
    Alpha.new.process
  end
  assert bar_is_called
end
```

Comment: Love this answer, definitely helped me. Just to add, if :bar expects an argument like `Foo.bar(some_arg)` you can add it to your lamba, e.g. `bar_lambda = ->(some_arg) { bar_is_called = true }`